# slow table update on SDO_GEOMETRY

Tags: database, oracle, sql-update

In Oracle, I have a tablespace called gpsinfo that records the locations of many cars. Each record has four attributes: 'PLATENO', 'SENDTIME', 'MILEAGE', and 'COORDINATES'. They represent the car's plate number, the time when the location was sent, the car's mileage, and the car's coordinates (LONGITUDE and LATITUDE) respectively. I added a column of type `SDO_GEOMETRY` to store the coordinates and created a spatial index on it.

```
ALTER TABLE gpsinfo ADD position SDO_GEOMETRY;

INSERT INTO user_sdo_geom_metadata (table_name, column_name, diminfo, srid)
VALUES (
  'gpsinfo', -- table name
  'position', -- column name
  SDO_DIM_ARRAY( -- dimensional information
    SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('LONGITUDE', -180, 180, 0.00001), -- longitude dimension
    SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('LATITUDE', -90, 90, 0.00001) -- latitude dimension
  ),
  4326 -- spatial reference system (WGS84)
);

CREATE INDEX gpsinfo_spatial_idx ON gpsinfo(position) INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;
```

To update data in the position column, I use `update`:

```
UPDATE gpsinfo
SET position = SDO_GEOMETRY(
  2001, -- two-dimensional point
  4326, -- WGS84
  SDO_POINT_TYPE(longitude, latitude, NULL), -- single point
  NULL, -- no element information
  NULL -- no ordinate array
);
```

However, the `update` operation is very slow. How can I improve the performance? Thank you very much!

Comment: Which Oracle database version (specify all decimals!) do you use?